# How to manually scroll using ItemsRepeater

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm using `ItemsRepeater`. And using a `ScrollViewer` to scroll left/right.

For some reason, I have to disable `ScrollViewer`' `HorizontalScrollMode`, and add Left/Right `Button` to manual scroll.

The xaml is

```
<Grid>
                    <muxc:ItemsRepeaterScrollHost Margin="12" Loaded="ItemsRepeaterScrollHost_Loaded">
                        <ScrollViewer
                            x:Name="sss"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                            VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                            HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
                            <muxc:ItemsRepeater
                                x:Name="HorizontalRepeater"
                                ItemsSource="{x:Bind product}"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HorizontalTemplate}">
                                <muxc:ItemsRepeater.Layout>
                                    <muxc:StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="12"/>
                                </muxc:ItemsRepeater.Layout>
                            </muxc:ItemsRepeater>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </muxc:ItemsRepeaterScrollHost>
                    <Button
                        x:Name="ButtonLeft"
                        Tapped="ButtonLeft_Tapped">
                        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE76B;" FontSize="18" />
                    </Button>

                    <Button x:Name="ButtonRight"
                        Tapped="ButtonRight_Tapped">
                        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE76C;" FontSize="18" />
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
```

Then I use

```
sss.ChangeView(step, null, null);
```

Nothing happens.
Why, thx.

Comment: What 's your app's target min version?

Comment: You have disable ScrollViewer `HorizontalScrollMode`, why call ChangeView with `horizontalOffset` ?

Comment: Because I set `HorizontalScrollMode` value to `Disable`, thus can prevent mouse wheel. And use `ChangeView` to manual change `ScrollViewer`'s horizontal offset.

Comment: As Pieter Nijs's blog, https://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2016/01/17/custom-uwp-control-step-through-listview/. He also set `ScrollMode` value to `Disable`, and use `ChangeView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to manually scroll using ItemsRepeater

For my testing, `ChangeView` can't works for `ItemsRepeater`, Please try replace it with [`ScrollToHorizontalOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltohorizontaloffset) or [`ScrollToVerticalOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset) method.

**Update**

After update OS to latest version (1909) `ChangeView` works well, It may be a issue within previous version.

Comment: Thanks, man. I will report it as a bug for WinUI. link: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1610