# ScrollingTextBlock not scrolling

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

I have a `TextView` that scrolls automatically if the current control (`MainMusicInfoGrid` of [`MediaControl`](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/MediaControl.xaml)) is not wide enough to hold the text. The text will scroll to the end and then to the start in a circular fashion. You can also see this effect in the Groove Music.

I implement this effect by creating a `UserControl` called [ScrollingTextBlock](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/ScrollingTextBlock.xaml.cs) and use a `ScrollViewer` to measure the width of the text. If it can be scrolled, then when I need to scroll it, instead of scrolling the original text, the new text (composed of original_text + new string(' ', 10) + original_text) will be scrolled. When it stops scrolling, I hide the new text.

This way is supposed to work and it worked well in the past. However, I just notice that currently only one `ScrollingTextBlock` (`MainArtistTextBlock` in the `MediaControl`) works while the other (`MainTitleTextBlock` in the `MediaControl`) does not.

I have found the problem, in the `timer.Tick` of the [`ScrollingTextBlock`](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/ScrollingTextBlock.xaml.cs), `RealScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset` is already equal to `offset` before `ChangeView`, which means that the hiding of new text doens't reset the `RealScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset` to 0. I tried manually resetting it to 0 in the `StopScrolling` but in the `timer.Tick` the value changes back to the offset.

I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me with this? It works for one but not for the other, I don't see the reason why.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I didn't use that because that's outdated and deprecated...

Comment: I run your code in my side, The text could be scrolled if the text out of the bound.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Glad to hear it works. I believe my code is good haha. I think the problem might come from Windows.

Comment: haha, what's your current os version?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT 1903

Comment: Is there any update notification in action center ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202693/discussion-between-seaky-lone-and-nico-zhu-msft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code, it works well, As you know [`ChangeView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58840796/7254781) method has some known issue in old version, please try to update your OS to latest version. And if you have any issue please feel free post within Windows **FeedBackHub** app.

Comment: Good, but I do not think the customer will update the os

Comment: Hello, I just upgraded my os to 1909. But it is still not working as expected. I can get it scrolling the first time, but it stay still on the second try.

Comment: I will test it again, please wait a moment.